# How to find current index of your list / array in a changing list?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of lets say 10 items on the first call:

```
 var myList = GetMyList();
```

okay now I get the item I want from this list:

```
 myList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

Now I go to the web page and do stuff.

Now I am back: The list Could have changed by this point if anything was deactivated through a rest call in my API. (I rebuild the current list in the constructor)

```
public OneItemFromMyList Get(int id)
{
     //Here I need the next item in the list after the one with the above Id
}
```

So how do I get that one. I do not want to repeat one that I retrieved before and I don't want to move outside of the list so I would need to start over if I am on the last position.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: You you give some sample data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an item immediately after the one with the specific `id`, do this:

```
var nextItem = myList.SkipWhile(x => x.Id != id).Take(2).LastOrDefault();
```

Note that this may not produce an item, if either of the following is true:

- The item with `x.Id == id` is not there, or
- The item with `x.Id == id` is the last item in the list.

Comment: would this stay in the index boundries of the array?

Comment: @Robert Yes. It may return `null` if the `id` isn't there, or if it is the last one.

Comment: How would you circumvent that?

Comment: @Robert Circumvent what? If the item is not there, you need a "plan B" on what to take. Add `if (nextItem == null) ...`, and pick whatever's the next thing in line.

Comment: k I was hoping for one line but thats fair

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you:

```
var nextId =
    myList
        .SkipWhile(x => x != id) //skip until x == id
        .Skip(1) // but I don't want x == id so skip one more
        .Concat(myList) // but item could be removed or I hit the end so restart
        .First(); // the first item is the one I want!
```